# Flask Socket.Io: Persistence of initialized socketio after import

Tags: python, flask, websocket, python-import, flask-socketio

So I have the following websocket server api:

```
//x.py
......
import y

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connected', namespace='/getDefects')
def connected():
    y.set_client_sid(request.sid)
    y.set_socketio(socketio)


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/getDefects')
def disconnect():
    print("Client disconnected")

def sendDefects(def, sid, socketio_input):
    socketio = socketio_input
    socketio.emit('defects', def, room=sid, namespace='/getDefects')


def processDefWithContext(text):
    with app.test_request_context():
        y.processDef(text)

@app.route('/Process', methods=['Post'])
def process():
    text = request.form.get('text') 
    thread1 = Thread(target = processDefWithContext, args = (text,))
    thread1.start()
    response = "Ok"
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)


//y.py
import x
....
clientSid = 0
socketIo = 0
def set_client(sid):
    clientSid = sid

def set_socketio(socket_in):
    socketIo = socket_in


processDef(text):
    ....
    def = ..
    x.sendDefects(def, clientSid, socketio)
```

So basically x.py contains a web api which processes both in and out requests.
It gets some data using a post request (*process*()) and at that point it will trigger some processing on that data in a new thread. The processing is done in y.py. After the processing is done, the new data needs to be sent to the frontend using a websocket from x.py
So x.py imports y.py and y.py imports x.py. The problem is that when we call from y.py the function to send the data (*sendDefects*(..)) from x.py, the socketio is no longer initialized and will not be able to send it.

The solution I found so far (I'm not an experienced Python programmer) is to send the socketio from x.py to y.py (*set_socketio*()) and back and then use it to send the data.

But this solution seem a bit ugly. Can you recommend another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a side effect of a weird thing that happens to the main module in Python applications. I assume you start your application as:

```
python x.py
```

Correct? In that case, your `x.py` module is named `__main__`, and not `x`. So the import sequence for your applications ends up creating two copies of your `x` module. This may not be very clear, so let me describe what happens in your app:

- The python interpreter imports `x.py`, and because it is the main module, it stores in the module list as `__main__`.
- The `__main__` module imports `y`, which is stored as `y`.
- The `y` module imports `x`. Here the interpreter decides that `x` has not been imported yet (since the existing instance of `x` is called `__main__`), so it imports a second copy of `x` under that name.
- So when `y` calls a function in `x`, it is invoking the duplicate, which has an uninitialized `socketio` variable. The reason why `socketio` is not initialized is that the initialization is wrapped in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` conditional, so that will only run in the first instance.

So how do you solve this? In `y.py`, replace your `import x` with:

```
import __main__ as x
```

That will ensure that you don't get a duplicate of `x`.

Comment: Hi. Ok I understand. Thanks for the solution. I will try it out.